# how do I make it so that it only takes up the width I want?

Tags: html, css, border

I have a border problem when making a button. The border takes up the entire width of the screen. I'd like it to take up only the width of the paragraph.

[img border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GttrF.png)

I'm a beginner in programming.

thank you in advance for your help

I've already tried it with and without the div.

it doesn't work.

Comment: See [ask] and edit your question to include a [mcve] please

Comment: The `<p>` is also a [block-level element.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p9) As is the `<div>`. 

Comment: Do you have tried with a `<span>`? 

Comment: Yes, with a <span> this works, but it puts it in the default alignment and not centered text.

Comment: @fatjul Give us some code we can work with

Comment: pls add your HTML  and css code for help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As no code was provided, from the image provided, I assume that by paragraph, you actually meant the text inside the button.

If you want to make the button the same width as the text inside it, all you have to do is write pure text between the button tags.

```
<button>Contactez-nous</button>
```

If the button still has full screen width, add the width style property to it.

```
<button style="width: fit-content">Contactez-nous</button>
```

Comment: yes but what should I do to center the button in the middle of my page ?

Comment: but your <button> tag is indeed already more suitable, thank you ^^

Comment: For centering the button you can apply `text-align: center` proptery to the parent element. You can use a `<div>` for doing so.

`<div style="text-align: center">
      <button>Contactez-nous</button>
</div>`